# SQL optimization : Inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Suppose I have got the SQL below

How can I optimize the performance of the query ?

```
select product, address, quantity, 
    price, create_date, sum(no_of_photo) as no_of_photo
from
(
    SELECT customer.PROJECT_ID as project_id ,
        customer.ORDER_TYPE as order_type,  
        customer.product_name as product, 
        customer.address_name as address ,    
        customer.quantity_name as quantity,
        user.first_name || ' ' || user.last_name AS price,
        customer.create_date, customer.no_of_photo 
    FROM customer 
    INNER JOIN user 
        ON customer.creation_userid = user.userid
) master_list 
group by project_id, order_type , 
    product, address, quantity, price, 
    create_date 
having project_id = 123456 
order by product, address, quantity, price, create_date
```

Comment: **Again**, why does it need optimization? What does the query optimizer say? Do any of these tables have indices (and, if so, on which columns)? **Think.**

Comment: See the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#i2061796

Comment: 0_0 If you don't know what a query optimizer is or how to get it to give you an execution plan for a query, then stop whatever it is you're doing and **do not** touch a production database again until you read and learn about these things.

Comment: It seems that your data-model is unnormal and naming convention is not correct. It seems that your USER table is actualy the CUSTOMER, and you have merged the PRODUCT and PURCHASE tables and name it CUSTOMER. Can you change the structure and normalize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things I would try:

1. Put your HAVING clause into a WHERE in the inner query
2. Select first_name and last_name on their own in inner query
3. Group by first_name, last_name in outer query (why is it called price?)
4. Do the concatenation of first_name || ' ' || last_name in outer query

Also ensure there are indexes on:

- customer.project_id
- customer.creation_userid
- user.userid

Comment: I think he should just move the join to user table to outer query, and move the group by and having into inner query. And if he is not filtering on first_name||' '||last_name then he shall change it to a sub-select

Answer (score 1):

The best increase normally comes by creating an index. You ask about the inner join. Is it fast without the inner join? Then you probably need an index on user.userid.

Comment: Possibly, but without knowing more about the OP's data, it's difficult at best to determine whether or not the query optimizer would make use of such an index.

Comment: I agree but that is where I would start. It is an educated guess. For me the whole question is a bit: I don't know much and here is the `SELECT` now tell me, please. My experience tells me that the missing index almost always is the problem. Probably, since you challenge it, an even better idea would be to try the subquery isolated. If slow then try without the join. If fast, try index. Then once the subquery is fast try the whole query and then if slow identify the problem. Explain would tell the story even easier.